# How to Restrict an Apache Module (Handler) to a Virtual Host (vhost)

Tags: c, apache-modules

I have an apache module which uses the `ap_hook_post_read_request` hook to perform an internal redirect when certain conditions are met. I would like to restrict this handler to a single virtual host but currently it fires on all virtual hosts (there are many). The httpd.conf configuration is limited to the `LoadModule` directive. I've tried using `SetHandler handlername` in the vhost and `SetHandler None` in the main config but the handler is still invoked on requests to other vhosts. The module also registers the `ap_register_output_filter` hook but the  output filter does not perform any action other than removing itself and passing control onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created some custom config in the vhost. I look for this config in the module and return if it doesn't have the config, so this in effect allows me to restrict the module to a vhost.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# VirtualHost1 = localhost:80

<IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/test/VirtualHost1"
ServerName localhost:80
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The issue is not that the handler isn't being invoked for a specific  vhost, but that it is being invoked on all vhosts and I only want it to apply to a single vhost